# Show the operator $I-iT$ is invertible and that $(I-iT)(I+iT)^{-1}$ is unitary operator

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I have $V$ an inner product space above $\mathbb{C}$ and a linear operator $T$ such as $T=T^{*}$ on $V$ (surjective).

I need to prove that the operators $I+iT$, $I-iT$ are invertible and that $U=\left(I-iT\right)\left(I+iT\right)^{-1}$ satisfies the condition $U^{*}=U^{-1}$, by $*$ I mean adjoint operator.

I know that:
$$\left\|v+iT(v)\right\|=\left\|v-iT(v)\right\|$$
$$v=0 \iff v+iT(v)=0$$

Will be thankful for your help, thank you.

***Edit:***

I shouldn't use the rule $(ST)^*=T^*S^*$ or any other rules without proving it, except the definition:
$<T(u),v>=<u,T^*(v)>$ and also I found that $(I+iT)^*=I-iT$.

Comment: fixed it, I ment the operators.

Comment: It might help improve readability to use the \iff ($\iff$) on the last line.

Comment: You seem to have a further typo in the text. What is the definition of $U$?  **HINT**: What do you know about the eigenvalues of a self-adjoint operator?

Comment: fixed it eather, sorry guys.

Answer (score 1):

Since $T^* = T$ for any $v \in V$ we have $\langle Tv,v\rangle \in \Bbb{R}$ so
$$\|(I+iT)v\|^2\|v\|^2 \ge |\langle (I+iT)v,v\rangle|^2 = |\|v\|^2 + i\langle Tv,v\rangle|^2 =\|v\|^4 + |\langle Tv,v\rangle|^2 \ge \|v\|^4$$
and therefore $\|(I+iT)v\| \ge \|v\|$ so the operator $I+iT$ is bounded from below. In particular it is injective and has closed range. Similarly we show that $I+iT$ is bounded from below. We now have
$$V = \overline{R(I+iT)} \oplus N((I+iT)^*) = \overline{R(I+iT)} \oplus N(I-iT) = R(I+iT) \oplus \{0\} = R(I+iT)$$
so $I+iT$ is surjective and injective, hence invertible.

As for the second claim, I believe it is false unless $T=0$. Namely, if $U = (I+iT)(I-iT) = I+T^2$ is unitary, then its spectrum is contained in the unit sphere so

$$1+\sigma(T)^2 = \sigma(U) \subseteq \mathbb{S}^1$$
and $\sigma(T)^2 \subseteq [0, +\infty\rangle$ so it follows $\sigma(T) = 0$ and from $T^*=T$ we get $T = 0$.

Comment: I had a typo in the second claim.

Comment: Yes, I see, for the second part, it just some math calculations. What is N and R in the first part proof ?

Comment: Is there easier way to say that I+iT is surjective ? 

as maybe it is a sum of surjective operators or some thing ? 

because Id is surjective and iT is surjective because it is a composition of T, so it is also surjective. Or any other way ?

Comment: @Ilya.K. If $I+iT$ is  not surjective then there exists a vector $y \neq 0$ which is  orthogonal to its range. From this you can easily show that $Ty=-iy$. But $T$ is self-adjoint, so the eigen values are real. It follows that $y=0$. Thus $I+iT$ is  surjective .

Comment: I thought I know to to prove the second part, but I don't know if T is invertible, so my math wasn't correct. How do I show the second part?

Comment: @Ilya.K. $N$ and $R$ stand for null-space and range, respectively. As Kavi suggests, if $I+iT$ is not surjective, then there is a vector $y \ne 0$ orthogonal to the range $R(I+iT)$. In particular we have $$0 = \langle y, (I+iT)(I-iT)y\rangle = \langle (I-iT)y, (I-iT)y\rangle = \|(I-iT)y\|^2$$
so $(I-iT)y = 0$. But this is a contradiction since $I-iT$ is also injective.

Comment: As for the second part, we have $$U^* = ((I+iT)^{-1})^*(I-iT)^* = ((I+iT)^*)^{-1}(I+iT) = (I-iT)^{-1}(I+iT)$$
so it easily follows that $U^*U = UU^* = I$ which proves your claim.

Comment: @mechanodroid , you have a calculation mistake. When you apply *, you should change them right to left, because $ST^*=T^*S^*$.

Comment: @Ilya.K. I did change them right to left, no? Anyway, it doesn't matter since $1\pm iT$ and $(1\pm iT)^{-1}$ all commute.